# Show current div size in html text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to show current the width and height of a div in another div. I use the `resize: both` on the div I am trying to measure. The problem I have now is that the numbers do not update when I resize the div.

```
  $(function () {
      var divheight = $("#resizediv").height();
      var divwidth = $("#resizediv").width();
      document.getElementById("divheightdisplay").innerHTML = divheight;
      document.getElementById("divwidthdisplay").innerHTML = divwidth;
  });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82rxvbfo/3/)

I also tried [CSS Element Queries](http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/). But have some problems with `overflow: hidden`

Comment: You would have to update them when resizing, https://api.jquery.com/resize/ for example http://jsfiddle.net/82rxvbfo/4/

Comment: How do you resize it actually? Manual through the css or...? Depends on how do you resize it, there are plenty of options.

Comment: Through css. `resize: both`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resize` event does not seem to apply to elements other than the `window`.

Instead, you could update based on the `mousemove` event:

```
$('#resizediv').on('mousemove', function() {
  var divheight = $(this).height(),
      divwidth = $(this).width();

  $('#divheightdisplay').html(divheight);
  $('#divwidthdisplay').html(divwidth);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ebwjejou/)

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly in your example. Cant see what i am missing here

http://jsfiddle.net/82rxvbfo/5/

Comment: Ahh! i was using old jQuery.. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the content of your divs are loaded dynamically, then you will need to use window.load event to get the correct size:

```
$(window).load(function() {
     var divheight = $("#resizediv").height();
     var divwidth = $("#resizediv").width();
     document.getElementById("divheightdisplay").innerHTML = divheight;
     document.getElementById("divwidthdisplay").innerHTML = divwidth;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call a callback function, which updates the values of width and height, on resizing your div.

```
//Say this is the function which is resizing your div
resize("#resizediv", callback());

function callback() {
    var divheight = $("#resizediv").height();
    var divwidth = $("#resizediv").width();
    document.getElementById("divheightdisplay").innerHTML = divheight;
    document.getElementById("divwidthdisplay").innerHTML = divwidth;
}
```